# How to invoke SCP command from Qt

Tags: qt

I want to copy files from local machine to remote server through SCP command. I was able to copy files through Cygwin. Now I want to achieve this thru Qt. How do I invoke 'SCP' command? If I make use of QProcess, then how will I get to know about password prompt?

Comment: Doesn't it works if you `write()` the password (as a `QByteArray`) to the `QProcess`'s standard input?

Comment: Just tried invoking `pg_dump` command (PostgreSQL backup utility) with a `QProcess` and then writing the password to its standard input as a `QByteArray`. To know when to `write()` I'm monitoring the standard error of the process (readyReadStandardError() SIGNAL). If the string `startsWith()` `"Password:"`, then I `write()` the password. It works just fine.

Comment: Definitely not the same. Tried `scp -v somefile me@localhost:/somewhere/somefile`.  A dialog pops up to prompt for the password. I think this is what user `robert` described in its answer. In short, it's not possible the write the password to the `QProcess`'s standard input.

Answer (score 0):

As fara as I know, you will hit the same issue with **scp** prompting for the password whichever way you try to call the command (even if you try writing a *bash* script that calls *scp*, for instance)
Possible solution I'm aware of includes:

- create a public/private key and distribute them so that you do not need to be prompted with the password. An interesting paper on the topic is [here](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/openssh-key-management-p1.xml)
- create an `expect` script and invoke it with QProcess

Answer (score 0):

Require your users to use public keys and your problem is solved: https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dhsu/ssh_public_key_howto.html

scp, ssh, sftp, etc. deliberately make it hard to take a password other than directly from the user. Specifically, things like `expect` will not work. And if they did, they wouldn't be secure.